# Oracle query with multiple IN clauses with more than 1000 values

Tags: oracle

Can we have oracle query with more than one IN clause, each could have 1000+ values?

```
select * from student where name in(1000+ values) and id in (1000+ values)
```

I have seen other threads with the same kind of question with single IN clause with a solution temp table

Thanks
-Ranadheer

Comment: this screams bad design to me. Create mutliple temp tables or one temp table with multiple columns if both are 1:1 (i.e. one name correlates to one Id). You do not want to pass 40kb worth of select - statements to your db on a regular basis....

Comment: MySQL's `IN` clauses can hold more literals that Oracle's. Which DBMS are you using? Please [edit] your tags.

Comment: Or you can just `OR` as many `IN(less than 1000)`  as needed.

Comment: Very bad design. Create a temp table if necessary and make `where name in (select name from temp_table)`

Comment: i can not do OR, it should be an AND, because this query is based on UI filter selection, and the filter is AND filter

Comment: @user2555212 - Don't be ridiculous, of course you can use OR. What Wernfried is saying is that your query is equivalent to `... where ( name in (900-names-list) or name in (900-names-list) or name in (500-names-list) ) AND ( id in (900-values-list) or id in (600-values-list) )` With that said, it makes absolutely no sense to do it this way. Where do the lists come from, anyway? Are they hard-coded - which means you are using dynamic SQL? Much better to save the values to two (temp?) tables and use `in ( select name from names_temp_table )` type conditions.

Answer (score 2):

the `IN` condition in another word  it mean `OR` for example :

`selecT * from table where col1 in('A','B','C')` it the same as 
`selecT * from table where col1 ='A' or col1 ='B' or col1 ='C'` so imagine your are adding OR to 1000+ expression , it is really bad for performance and design so why you need to use it ? as an alternative you can create a temp table and add the values in it and select from it for example

```
create table_tmp (SOME_EXPRESSION varchar2(1000) null)
insert into table_tmp  (SOME_EXPRESSION ) values ('some condition');
commit;

 select * from tab1 where col1 in (select SOME_EXPRESSION  from table_tmp )
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, as of [Oracle 12.2](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/IN-Condition.html) the restriction remains:

```
{ expr [ NOT ] IN ({ expression_list | subquery })
| ( expr [, expr ]... )
    [ NOT ] IN ({ expression_list [, expression_list ]...
                | subquery
                }
               )
}
```

```
{ expr [, expr ]...
| ( [expr [, expr ]] ...)
}
```

> You can specify up to 1000 expressions in `expression_list`.

If temp tables are the only problem, you must be aware than the 1,000 item restriction only applies to individual `IN()` conditions, so you can always `OR` as many of them as needed:

```
select *
from student
where 
    (name in(1, 2, …, 1000) or name in(1001, 1002, …, 2000) or …)
    and (id in (1, 2, …, 1000) or id in (1001, 1002, …, 2000) or …)
```